# OpenGL: Draw a line over another

Tags: opengl, lines, overlapping, depth-buffer

I am programming a code in OpenGL in which I want to draw a line over another. The first drawn line should disappear but instead there is interference between them.

#### Image that illustrates this:

[image: Diagram]

Is there anything I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Polygon Offset](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPolygonOffset.xml) will do that ([sample code](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/Courses/570/UserGuide/OpenGLonWin-14.html)). Remember that you must enable `GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE` in addition to calling `glPolygonOffset` (as explained on the linked manpage).

If these are actually drawn using `GL_LINES`, then as pointed out by Andon M. Coleman, this will not work. In that case, use [`glDepthRange`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glDepthRange.xml) to a similar (almost identical effect).

How to do that is explained on the OpenGL [FAQ #13.050](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/polygonoffset.htm).

Comment: `glPolygonOffset` is literally only for polygon primitives. This would only work if the OP were using something like `GL_TRIANGLES` and a `glPolygonMode (...)` to generate the lines. I get the impression that `GL_LINES` are actually being used.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: In case those are really `GL_LINES` (looks like "normal geometry, e.g. a cube and a tesselated sphere to me, though), one would need to play with `glDepthRange` or set back the view matrix by a small bias manually.